# Get value from object key inside JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Result of arr[0].price is 'undefined' outside of the function. Why is the variable arr not available when it is defined outside of the function and data is pushed to it?

```
var arr = [];

function get_data() {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://bitcoinprice.co.uk/site-options/',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        var price = data['gbp_price'];
        var abs_change = data['gbp_abs_change'];
        var p_change = data['gbp_change'];
        var market_cap = data['gbp_market_cap'];
        var today_max = data['gbp_today_max'];
        var today_min = data['gbp_today_min'];

        var obj = {
            'price'      : 50,
            'abs_change' : abs_change,
            'p_change'   : p_change,
            'market_cap' : market_cap,
            'max'        : today_max,
            'min'        : today_min
        };

        arr.push(obj);
        console.log(arr[0].price); // 50
      }

    });

}
get_data();

console.log(arr[0].price) // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined(…)
```

I can't seem to find an answer to this. I am trying to get the value from the key 'price' outside of the function get_data().

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: try `arr[0].price`

Comment: Javascript has no associative arrays, only index-based arrays.

Comment: Returns "Cannot read property 'price' of undefined(…)"

Comment: @Nick, that's can't be true. Just open a console and run the code. It works.

Comment: @Maximus ... you're right. Something else going on here.

Comment: I've updated my question to show the scoping issues.

Comment: Because it is not loaded yet! your get_data() function did not the complete the request. so your arr is still empty

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `arr[0].price`, because the `price` property is defined not on array, but on the object, that is the first entry in the array.

You code can be rewritten like that to demonstrate what's happening:

```
var o = {'price':price};
o.price; // 50
arr.push(o);
arr[0] === o; // true
```

You would have to do like this to actually assign a property to the array:

```
arr.price = price;
```

Comment: Ignore, your code works, as does mine. I simplified my issue and it eliminated some scope issues that are causing the problem. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Nick, glad it helped. Good luck

Comment: rather than creating a new question I've updated it to show the scoping issues.

Comment: @Nick, don't forget, you can accept my answer if gives you correct explanation

Answer (score 0):

Just another option

```
var price = 50,
        arr = [];
arr.price = price;

console.log(arr.price+'<br>'+arr['price']); // both return 50
```

Comment: I've updated my question to show the scoping issues.

Answer (score 0):

var arr is none other than array of objects. You just needed to loop in the array to get value.

```
var price = 50;
var arr = [];

var obj = {
    'price' : price
}

arr.push(obj);

for(var i of arr)
    {
    console.log(i['price']); //50
    }
```

Comment: I've updated my question to show the scoping issues.

Comment: Are you sure there is a scoping issue in your question? I get output 50 out of the block too!